# What function looks like a tangent on its side?

Tags: limits, functions, graphing-functions

Basically, I want a curve that decreases toward a lower limit as x approaches negative infinity and rises toward an upper limit as x approaches positive infinity - It would have this general shape:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_curve

The closest I could find to a description is a non-repeating tangent laid on its side.

I am sure I have seen something similar before; I just wish I had gone further in my study of trig and calculus...

Comment: The arctangent function?

Comment: It seems to me some of the "features" of the graph shown on the Wikipedia page are just accidents of that particular example. For example, just relabel goods X and Y as Y and X; now the curve looks more like a regular tangent. In general, I don't think the contract curve has to be S-shaped at all; a straight line from corner to corner is possible, or it might be curved in one direction only, or other shapes.

Comment: @CameronBuie, something like the arctan is what I was looking for, although the tanh curve suggested in Christian's answer is actually closer to what I really wanted.

Comment: Another possibility is a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples are
$$f(x):=\arctan x\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)$$
with $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm{\pi\over2}$, and
$$g(x):=\tanh x\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)$$
with $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=\pm1$.
Their graphs look similar, but there is an essential difference:
$${\pi\over2}-\arctan x=O\left({1\over x}\right),\quad 1-\tanh x=O(e^{-x})\qquad(x\to \infty)\ .$$

Comment: Thanks Christian. That is what I was looking for.  For my application, the hyperbolic tangent fit best.  Thanks for explaining it clearly!

Answer (score 0):

For example $\sqrt{x^2+1}/x$ will be between -1 and 1.

Comment: Or rather, $x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Comment: @Michael that is exactly what I wanted! I modified it slightly to get the result I wanted: (4x-2)/(sqrt((4x-2)^2+1))/2+.5

Comment: @Joe Why Michael and not Moti?

Comment: @Moti, you had almost the right answer, but if it hadn't been for Michael I would have assumed it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting about the line $x=y$, $y=\tan(x)$ becomes $y=\arctan(x)$:

[image]

However, to get something of the shape in the given link, we can use
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-2x+2x^2}
$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I was looking for until I get past x=1, where y approaches .5 in infinity.

Comment: Nothing was said about approaching infinity. [This example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b9/Contract-curve-on-edgeworth-box.svg) was given, which appears to have a finite domain. We can spread out the function above as $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ which tends to $1$ as $x$ tend to infinity.

Comment: You're right - I just said "as it increases", not "as it approaches infinity".  I have modified it to make it clearer.  Thanks!